# A question from my textbook (AS LEVEL STATS, PERMUTATIONS)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways 4 men and 2 women can stand in a line if no two men may stand next to each other

The answer to the question is 0.

Comment: I did complete it now, Sorry my bad

Comment: What is your question, and what have you tried? There is nothing but a statement in the question body.

Comment: How many ways 4 men and 2 women can stand in a line if no two men may stand next to each other

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't need mathematics. Just look at the picture below

$M-M-M-M$

If no two men are to stand next to each other, the $3$ gaps between them must be filled, but there are only $2$ women available, ergo it is impossible.

Comment: Ohhh, okay thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the person on the end of the line is a woman. Then, the person standing next to her must be a man, who in turn must to be standing next to a woman. Continuing this line of reasoning suggests that there is no way for this to be achieved if a woman is on the end of a row. The same can be done for when a man is standing on the end of a row.

Comment: I got you but is there any mathematical way of proving ths?